# Divisibility Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

For all integers a, b, c, if a | (b + c), then a | b and a | c
True or false?

Im assuming it's false because if you make a=2 b=3 and c=4, it won't work

Comment: You're correct, it is false. All you need to prove that a conjecture is false is to provide a counterexample, but can you find one that satisfies the premise?

Comment: @amWhy : Not sure that $2$ divides $7$.

Comment: @user102591 : Your example is wrong, because $2$ does not divide $3+4 = 7$... but of course the statement is false! Can you think of another example?

Comment: heres another example: For all integers a, b, c, if a | b and b | c then a | c

Comment: wouldnt it be false also because if you use the same variables, the outcome with be false

Comment: ^that is true, and shows the transitivity of the relation "|"

Comment: can you explain why it's true/

Comment: and also is this false? for all integers a, b, c, if a | bc, then a | b or a | c

Comment: @user102591 Also false, consider $a = bc$.

Comment: @user102591 : Your last comment is a possible definition of prime numbers, so I would say that it is not true for all $a$. :P

Comment: For all integers a, b, c, if a | b and b | c then a | c. This would be false also right?

Comment: No, that one is actually true.

Comment: Can you explain that one to me?

Comment: If $a | b$ and $b | c$, then $b = ma, c = nb$ for some integers $m, n$. Now, can you express $c$ as a product of $m, n, a$?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this kind of example  : $a = 2, b = c = 3$. You have 
$$
a = 2 \, | \, 6 = 3+3 = b+c,
$$
but $2$ does not divide $3$, hence divides neither $b$ or $c$.

Hope that helps,